# How to load external or custom fonts in subtitle file

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

How to load fonts in .ass subtitle file from an external file path/custom path? Suppose I have a font in a folder, and I need to load that font in subtitle file(.ass) file. how to load it? Is there any possibility?
FFmpeg command is

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -map 0 -vf "subtitles=test.ass:fontsdir=Dancing_Script.ttf" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Above is my .ass file

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,8,10,10,10,1


[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,first{\fnDancing Script\b0}
```

Problem is video is still loading Arial Font even I load with {\fnDancing Script\b0}

Answer (score 3):

## Softsubs

Name the specific font in the ASS file. The font name is in the `Style` line. In this example the font name is `Liberation Sans`.

```
Style: Default,Liberation Sans,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,8,10,10,10,1
```

Attach the subtitles and the font file with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subtitles.ass -attach LiberationSans-Regular.ttf -map 0 -map 1 -metadata:s:t mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -c copy output.mkv
```

## Hardsubs

Use the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) with the `fontsdir` and `force_style` options.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -vf "subtitles=/path/to/your/subtitles.ass:fontsdir=/path/to/your/font/directory:force_style='Fontname=Liberation Sans'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- Recommend putting the font file by itself in the specified `fontsdir`. Otherwise `ffmpeg` will take a long time loading **all** files in the specified `fontsdir`.
- This works with text-based subtitle format such as ASS, SRT, and VTT.
- Instead of using `force_style` you can directly edit the `Fontname` in ASS files as shown above.

## Multiple font styles

Use the [\fn override tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Cfn) to make particular words or sentences use a different font.

```
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,This is {\fnDancing Script}one font style{\fn} and this is {\fnArial}another font style{\fn}
```

Comment: how to attach ttf with follwing cmd 
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "subtitles=subs.ass" -c:a copy output.mkv

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya See updated answer. It was not clear if you wanted softsubs or hardsubs so I originally had to guess.

Comment: Thanks, What if I want to load separate fonts for different text, How do i format .ass file and ffmpeg command

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya See the [`\fn` override tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#\fn) for ASS files and if it is also "external" to your system make sure the font file is in the specified `fontsdir`.

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya See updated answer. It was not clear in the original question that you wanted multiple font styles.

Comment: So , there will be a change in ffmpeg cmd also right ? what Style: Default,Liberation S line consits of ?

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya No change in ffmpeg command. Only change `Dialog` in ASS file. No change needed for `Style` line. You set main font in `Style`, then others with `{\fn}`

Comment: Still working on it Ilogon. will update you Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This thing is pretty common, but I am a little bit disappointed at first as there are very few search results related to it when trying to find.

The llogan's answer is maybe correct, but I changed it a little bit to make it work for me, here I will share that so that maybe someone finds it useful.

This is not a complete example, as I guess you already added the .ass font file with your video. As llogan said, you can specify the font directory like this.

```
ass=./subt/113.ass:fontsdir=./fonts/
```

Then you can use any '.ttf' fonts files that are directly placed directly on the folder on your .ass file. like this.

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,FONT-NAME,40,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,0,0,2,40,40,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:03.55,Default,,0,0,0,,{\fnFONT-NAME\fs28}This is an example text.
```

In this above example, I assume that **FONT-NAME** is a font that is placed in the `./fonts/` folder. I used **FONT-NAME** which is the font name, (not the filename with .ttf extension.)